# Flickering screen in windows 10

Tags: windows, display, windows-10

I have been getting a flickering screen since I installed Windows 10. It flickers just as it would if the graphics drivers crashed and restarted, but I don't get that message. The computer can run for 1-3 hours without it happening, and it doesn't seem to happen in games at all, only on the desktop.

I've been monitoring the event-viewer each time it happens and it seems like its scheduled because it happened exactly at 3:07:00am last time. I've also reinstalled windows but it persists. This is some of what I got in the event-viewer, I'm just going to be as thorough as possible here.

```
"Tjänsten Software Protection startas.
Parametrar:caller=rundll32.exe"

"Initieringsstatus för serviceobjekt.
C:\Windows\system32\sppwinob.dll, msft:spp/windowsfunctionality/agent/7.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:rm/algorithm/inherited/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:rm/algorithm/phone/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:rm/algorithm/pkey/detect, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/ActionScheduler/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/TaskScheduler/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/statecollector/pkey, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/volume/services/kms/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
C:\Windows\system32\sppobjs.dll, msft:spp/volume/services/kms/activationinfo/1.0, 0x00000000, 0x00000000"
```

Plus a couple of lines about software protection.

It has stopped now since i installed a new graphics card. Changed from AMD to Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue in Windows 10 Insider preview for a while now. I have narrowed it down to either Intel graphics drivers and Dell monitors. I also tried changing from 60hz to 59Hz and that seems to have helped.

Comment: I cannot change to 59hz. Its locked at 60hz. same thing happened just now and same lines in event-viewer.